# PySpark SparkSession error when trying to write parquet files to S3 bucket: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

New to Spark and data engineering as a whole. I wrote a Spark application (on my local) that's meant to use Spark SQL to push parquet files to an S3 bucket. My code fails at this point in the file:

Config:

```
os.environ['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'] = config['AWS']['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID']
os.environ['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'] = config['AWS']['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']

spark = SparkSession.builder\
                    .config("spark.jars.packages", "org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:3.2.0,com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:1.12.369")\
                    .config('spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider', 'org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.SimpleAWSCredentialsProvider')\
                    .getOrCreate()
```

Part of the code that fails (where calendar_dim, etc are spark.sql dataframes):

```
output_path = "s3a://i94immigration/"
calendar_dim.write.parquet(output_path + "calendar_dim", partitionBy=['year', 'month', 'week'], mode="overwrite") 
us_demographics_dim.write.parquet(output_path + "us_demographics_dim", partitionBy='state_code', mode="overwrite")
us_airport_dim.write.parquet(output_path + "us_airport_dim", mode="overwrite")
country_dim.write.parquet(output_path + "country_dim", mode="overwrite")
immigration_fact.write.parquet(output_path + "immigration_fact", mode="overwrite")
```

The full error:

```
raise Py4JJavaError(
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o865.parquet.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors$.jobAbortedError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala:651)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:278)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:186)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:113)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.executeCollect(commands.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.$anonfun$applyOrElse$1(QueryExecution.scala:98)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$6(SQLExecution.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:169)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:95)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:779)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:98)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:94)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDownWithPruning$1(TreeNode.scala:584)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:176)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDownWithPruning(TreeNode.scala:584)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning(AnalysisHelper.scala:267)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning$(AnalysisHelper.scala:263)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:560)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.eagerlyExecuteCommands(QueryExecution.scala:94)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:81)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted(QueryExecution.scala:79)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertCommandExecuted(QueryExecution.scala:116)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:860)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:390)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveInternal(DataFrameWriter.scala:363)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.parquet(DataFrameWriter.scala:793)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 12.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 12.0 (TID 53) (192.168.0.22 executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors$.taskFailedWhileWritingRowsError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala:655)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:348)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.$anonfun$write$21(FileFormatWriter.scala:256)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:136)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:548)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1504)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:551)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.util.SemaphoredDelegatingExecutor.<init>(Lcom/google/common/util/concurrent/ListeningExecutorService;IZ)V
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.create(S3AFileSystem.java:772)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:1195)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:1175)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.util.HadoopOutputFile.create(HadoopOutputFile.java:74)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileWriter.<init>(ParquetFileWriter.java:329)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(ParquetOutputFormat.java:482)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(ParquetOutputFormat.java:420)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(ParquetOutputFormat.java:409)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetOutputWriter.<init>(ParquetOutputWriter.scala:36)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat$$anon$1.newInstance(ParquetFileFormat.scala:155)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.BaseDynamicPartitionDataWriter.renewCurrentWriter(FileFormatDataWriter.scala:298)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DynamicPartitionDataSingleWriter.write(FileFormatDataWriter.scala:365)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatDataWriter.writeWithMetrics(FileFormatDataWriter.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatDataWriter.writeWithIterator(FileFormatDataWriter.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.$anonfun$executeTask$1(FileFormatWriter.scala:331)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1538)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:338)
    ... 9 more

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2672)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2608)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2607)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2607)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1182)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1182)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1182)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2860)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2802)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2791)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:952)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2228)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:245)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors$.taskFailedWhileWritingRowsError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala:655)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:348)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.$anonfun$write$21(FileFormatWriter.scala:256)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:136)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:548)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1504)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:551)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.util.SemaphoredDelegatingExecutor.<init>(Lcom/google/common/util/concurrent/ListeningExecutorService;IZ)V
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.create(S3AFileSystem.java:772)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:1195)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:1175)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.util.HadoopOutputFile.create(HadoopOutputFile.java:74)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileWriter.<init>(ParquetFileWriter.java:329)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(ParquetOutputFormat.java:482)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(ParquetOutputFormat.java:420)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(ParquetOutputFormat.java:409)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetOutputWriter.<init>(ParquetOutputWriter.scala:36)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat$$anon$1.newInstance(ParquetFileFormat.scala:155)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.BaseDynamicPartitionDataWriter.renewCurrentWriter(FileFormatDataWriter.scala:298)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DynamicPartitionDataSingleWriter.write(FileFormatDataWriter.scala:365)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatDataWriter.writeWithMetrics(FileFormatDataWriter.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatDataWriter.writeWithIterator(FileFormatDataWriter.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.$anonfun$executeTask$1(FileFormatWriter.scala:331)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1538)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:338)
    ... 9 more
```

I can confirm I am able to read and write simple csv/txt files to the S3 bucket. Also, the parquet worked objects are created normally when writing to my local storage. I've done a lot of googling/reading and I'm not sure where I'm going wrong here. Would love some guidance.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out there was a dependency issue with the Hadoop version I was using. Changing the hadoop-aws version to 3.2.2 solved the issue for me.

```
spark = SparkSession.builder\
                    .config("spark.jars.packages", "org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:3.2.2,com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:1.12.369")\
                    .config('spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider', 'org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.SimpleAWSCredentialsProvider')\
                    .getOrCreate()
```